# efficiently look-up data from one data.frame in another data.frame by group

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, data.table, lookup

I am looking for a faster solution for the following problem.

Suppose I have the following two data-sets.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Var1 = c(5011, 2484, 4031, 1143, 7412),
              Var2 = c(2161, 2161, 2161, 2161, 8595))
df2 <- data.frame(team=c("A","A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D"),
              class=c("5011", "2161", "2484", "4031", "1143", "2161", "5011", "8595", "1143"),
              attribute=c("X1", "X2", "X1", "Z1", "Z2", "Y1", "X1", "Z1", "X2"),
              stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


> df1
  Var1 Var2
1 5011 2161
2 2484 2161
3 4031 2161
4 1143 2161
5 7412 8595

> df2
  team class attribute
1    A  5011        X1
2    A  2161        X2
3    B  2484        X1
4    B  4031        Z1
5    B  1143        Z2
6    C  2161        Y1
7    C  5011        X1
8    D  8595        Z1
9    D  1143        X2
```

I would like to know which teams in `df2` meet in `class` that correspond to **rows** in `df1`. I am not interested in order with-in rows.

My current code (pasted below) works, but is hopelessly inefficient.

Some rules:

- only team A and C meet in classes that occur as rows in `df1`.
- team B and team D do not meet in classes for which any pair-wise combination form a row in `df1`. They are excluded from the output.

Code:

```
    teams <- c()
    atts <- c()
    pxs <- unique(df2$team)

    for(j in pxs){
     subs <- subset(df2, team==j)
     for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
      if(all(df1[i,] %in% subs$class)){
    teams <- rbind(teams, subs$team[i])
    atts <- rbind(atts, subs$attribute)
     } 
     }
    }

    output <- cbind(teams, atts)  

> output
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "A"  "X1" "X2"
[2,] "C"  "Y1" "X1"
```

The original data consists of millions of rows in both `df1` and `df2`.

How to do this more efficiently? Perhaps through an `apply` approach combined with `data.table`?

Comment: Why not `merge` or `join`? What is your expected output? `merge(df1, df2, by.x = "Var1", by.y = "class")`. And can you clarify on why `B` doesn't match? It looks like it should.

Comment: Can you be a little more clear as to your expected results? Perhaps provide a few more cases of what would be included and not included in the results.

Comment: 2484, 4031, and 1143 all occur in df1. What do you mean by saying that B doesn't meet in classes that occur in df1?

Comment: So what if `B` was `2484, 9999, 2161`? Are they in or out?

Comment: `- team B does not meet in classes that form a row in df1 - thus not meet the criteria` This edit is still unclear with the data you present. What are the rules for inclusion/exclusion?

Comment: @JasonAizkalns : team B would be in because we can make the combination of row two in df1. I apologize for being vague here.

Comment: So you want cases where at least two of the classes for a certain team appear on the same row in df1? In your actual data, how many "classes" are there per "team", roughly? Because the number of possible combinations can skyrocket pretty quickly...

Comment: @iod Some teams attend 25 classes. Thanks for getting into this.

Comment: @wake_wake: your code is slow because you're growing objects within `for-loop` which is highly inefficient and not recommended in `R`. Please see these great posts to find out better ways to do it: [Efficient accumulation in R](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2015/07/efficient-accumulation-in-r/), 
[Applying a function over rows of a data frame](https://rpubs.com/wch/200398)

Comment: @Tung: Thank you. I am aware that the `for` loop is awfully slow and at the core of the problem here. How would you write this up (applying a function)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what your rules are trying to achieve.

Based on your sample data, code and output, you might want to join by each column of df1 first then inner join the 2 results:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)[, cls := as.integer(cls)]

#left join df1 with df2 using Var1
v1 <- df2[df1, on=.(cls=Var1)]

#left join df1 with df2 using Var2
v2 <- df2[df1, on=.(cls=Var2)]

#inner join the 2 previous results to ensure that the same team is picked 
#where classes already match in v1 and v2
v1[v2, on=.(team, cls=Var1, Var2=cls), nomatch=0L]
```

output:

```
   team  cls attribute Var2 i.attribute
1:    A 5011        X1 2161          X2
2:    C 5011        X1 2161          Y1
```

Comment: Thanks! This is works great and is much faster than the original code.